# How do you format the default mongoose Date?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose in an express app and my schema contains a Date property, which uses **Date.now** . The problem is, data is always in this format "**2021-02-14T16:04:13.373Z**" which I do not really enjoy. Is there an easy way to format this to date only without time, or at least without this part "**:13.373Z**"? Any help would be appreciated. Also, here is the schema, just in case:

```
const schema = {
date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}
```

Comment: I think,it is not possible, you can change format in server side

Answer (score 1):

It's already late for my answer but hopefully it will help someone else because it's a good question. We can format the default date by just adding a getter like this:

```
const schema =  new Schema({
  date: {
      type: Date, 
      default: Date.now,
      get: (date)=> date.toLocaleDateString("en-US") // getter
     }
})
```

`get: (date)=> date.toLocaleDateString("en-US")`

This getter will give us a formated date in this format "MM-DD-YYYY".

If we want another format like "DD-MM-YYYY" we can change this `("en-US")`
to `("sp-MX")`.

If we just do this `get: (date)=> date.toLocaleDateString()` I think the date will be formated according to your location but I'm not totally sure, but you can try to change the format inside the round brackets, it totally worked for me.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the way MongoDb stores the date, but you can always change the format in the response of the Query using `$dateToString`.

You cannot use `$dateToString` on `find` queries. You need to use the `aggregate pipelines` to format the date into your desired format.

You can refer to full documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)